# How to efficiently delete rows based on a comparison

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro that will filter a range of data that includes a "Unit ID" and a "Sample Date" column.  To do this, I have a separate range that has "Unit ID" and "Install Date" columns.

[image: Example of units, sample dates, and install dates]

Right now I'm running a loop that uses `Application.VLookup` to check each row's unit's install date, and then deletes the row if `sample_date < install_date`.

The problem is that I have ~14,000 rows, which seems to take forever to do this.  My question is: is there a more efficient way of doing this that will reduce the time required to perform the operation?

My code currently looks like this (pared down a bit for clarity):

```
j = 2

Do
    unit = Sheets("930E Samples").Cells(j, 49)
    install_date = Application.VLookup(unit, Lookup_Range, 5, False)

    If IsError(install_date) Then
        install_date = 1000000 'sets the date so that samples are deleted (because unit does not exist)
    End If


Do
    If Sheets("930E Samples").Cells(j, 3) < install_date Then
        Sheets("930E Samples").Cells(j, 3).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        j = j - 1
    End If
    j = j + 1
    next_unit = Sheets("930E Samples").Cells(j + 1, 49)
Loop While unit = next_unit

Loop While (j < Sheets("930E Samples").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
```

I admit that it's certainly not the best way to do this right now, but it does work (although it takes around 5-10 minutes).

Comment: How about a non-vba solution. In cell C2 place this formula = `=IF(B2<VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$F$3,2,0),"Delete","")` Then drag down, filter on column C for `Delete` and delete the visible cells. Or if you need the VBA, you can just have VBA do the steps I wrote.

Comment: Turn off you calculations at the beginning of the code and turn them back on again at the end it will speed it up.

Comment: @ScottCraner That's definitely one of the usual suspects.  I have both calculations and screen updating turned off at the start of the code.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I like this idea.  Currently working on integrating it into the larger framework of my workbook.  Will let you know if it works.

Comment: Turn off animation too.

Comment: @Seb `Application.Screenupdating = False`

Comment: @n8 Application.EnableAnimations = false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using an additional column next to "sample date" that contains the formula Scott Holtzman suggested (cell references removed for clarity):

```
IF(sample_date < VLOOKUP(blah), "DELETE", "")
```

Then, because I was able to put my data in a table, I used the following code to eliminate the unwanted rows:

```
Sub Filter_By_Date()
Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE
Application.Calculations = xlCalculationsManual

With Sheets("930E Samples")
    .ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter Field:=50, Criteria1:="<>"
    .Range("Table29[Delete?]").EntireRow.Delete

    If .Range("Table29").ListObject.ShowAutoFilter Then
        .ListObjects(1).AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE
Application.Calculations = xlCalculationsAutomatic
End Sub
```

Again, some golfing is probably required here to clean up the references and syntax, but this method of having the spreadsheet provide a built-in filtering column and then deleting rows using VBA resulted in a much faster operation.

Comment: You might also consider filtering, copying the entire visible sheet contents to a new sheet, then deleting the old sheet.  When data sets get very large it becomes time consuming to delete rows.